# Dynamic allocation and random access: Raw, Smart, Deque, Vector. Why raw so fast, and deque so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, deque

I created a little performance test comparing the setup and access times of three popular techniques for dynamic allocation: raw pointer, std::unique_ptr, and a std::deque.

EDIT: per @NathanOliver's, added `std::vector`:
EDIT 2: per latedeveloper's, allocated with std::vector(n) and std::deque(n) constructors
EDIT 3: per @BaummitAugen, moved allocation inside timing loop, and compiled an optimized version.
EDIT 4: per @PaulMcKenzie's comments, set runs to 2000.

Results: These changes have tightened things up a lot. Deque and Vector are still slower on allocation and assignment, while deque is much slower on access:

pickledEgg$ g++ -std=c++11 -o sp2 -O2 sp2.cpp

```
Average of 2000 runs:
Method  Assign          Access
======  ======          ======
Raw:    0.0000085643    0.0000000724
Smart:  0.0000085281    0.0000000732
Deque:  0.0000205775    0.0000076908
Vector: 0.0000163492    0.0000000760
```

Just for fun, here are -Ofast results:
pickledEgg$ g++ -std=c++11 -o sp2 -Ofast sp2.cpp

```
Average of 2000 runs:
Method  Assign          Access
======  ======          ======
Raw:    0.0000045316    0.0000000893
Smart:  0.0000038308    0.0000000730
Deque:  0.0000165620    0.0000076475
Vector: 0.0000063442    0.0000000699
```

ORIGINAL: For posterity; note lack of optimizer -O2 flag:

pickledEgg$ g++ -std=c++11 -o sp2 sp2.cpp

```
Average of 100 runs:
Method  Assign      Access
======  ======      ======
Raw:    0.0000466522    0.0000468586
Smart:  0.0004391623    0.0004406758
Deque:  0.0003144142    0.0021758729
Vector: 0.0004715145    0.0003829193
```

Updated Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

const int NUM_RUNS(2000);

int main() {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point b, e;
    std::chrono::duration<double> t, raw_assign(0), raw_access(0), smart_assign(0), smart_access(0), deque_assign(0), deque_access(0), vector_assign(0), vector_access(0);
    int k, tmp, n(32768);

    std::cout << "Average of " << NUM_RUNS << " runs:" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "Method " << '\t' << "Assign" << "\t\t" << "Access" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "====== " << '\t' << "======" << "\t\t" << "======" << std::endl;

    // Raw
    for (k=0; k<NUM_RUNS; ++k) {
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        int* raw_p = new int[n]; // run-time allocation
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //assign
            raw_p[i] = i;
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        raw_assign+=t;
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //access
            tmp = raw_p[i];
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        raw_access+=t;
        delete [] raw_p; // :^)
    }
    raw_assign /= NUM_RUNS;
    raw_access /= NUM_RUNS;
    std::cout << "Raw:   " << '\t' << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed << raw_assign.count() << '\t' << raw_access.count() << std::endl;

    // Smart
    for (k=0; k<NUM_RUNS; ++k) {
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::unique_ptr<int []> smart_p(new int[n]); // run-time allocation
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //assign
            smart_p[i] = i;
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        smart_assign+=t;
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //access
            tmp = smart_p[i];
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        smart_access+=t;
    }
    smart_assign /= NUM_RUNS;
    smart_access /= NUM_RUNS;
    std::cout << "Smart: " << '\t' << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed << smart_assign.count() << '\t' << smart_access.count() << std::endl;

    // Deque
    for (k=0; k<NUM_RUNS; ++k) {
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::deque<int> myDeque(n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //assign
            myDeque[n] = i;
//          myDeque.push_back(i);
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        deque_assign+=t;
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //access
            tmp = myDeque[n];
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        deque_access+=t;
    }
    deque_assign /= NUM_RUNS;
    deque_access /= NUM_RUNS;
    std::cout << "Deque: " << '\t' << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed << deque_assign.count() << '\t' << deque_access.count() << std::endl;

    // vector
    for (k=0; k<NUM_RUNS; ++k) {
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::vector<int> myVector(n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //assign
            myVector[i] = i;
//          .push_back(i);
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        vector_assign+=t;
        b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { //access
            tmp = myVector[i];
//          tmp = *(myVector.begin() + i);
        }
        e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(e - b);
        vector_access+=t;
    }
    vector_assign /= NUM_RUNS;
    vector_access /= NUM_RUNS;
    std::cout << "Vector:" << '\t' << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed << vector_assign.count() << '\t' << vector_access.count() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `deque` is not like an array.  You should compare the performance to a `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, please share how you invoke your compiler. A lot of people measure unoptimized/debug builds, which is utterly useless.

Comment: Use the `std::deque(n)` or `std::vector(n)` constructor.

Comment: To get times anywhere near these, I have to run in debug mode. With optimizations, there is no difference between raw pointer and `unique_ptr`. The `deque` is a lot slower because you include the memory allocations in the timing.

Comment: ^Right now, you are measuring the allocation time of the container and not the allocation time of the raw arrays. You must *at least* reserve enough memory beforehand for a somewhat fair comparison.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, ``g++ -std=c++11 -o sp2 sp2.cpp``

Comment: Use `-O2` or `-O3` and see what happens

Comment: @BaummitAugen, allocation (and deallocatin) of the raw array occurs within the loop.

Comment: @kmiklas Unless you're timing an optimized build, the results are meaningless.  With over a 2K rep, this should have been a given.

Comment: @kmiklas But not within the segment you time.

Comment: @BaummitAugen oops!

Comment: [Results when compiled with optimizations turned on](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2550b6d03cd2ee1f)

Comment: Updated per the above comments.

Comment: You are still comparing apples to oranges.  Timing `std::vector<int> myVector(n);` is not the same as `int* raw_p = new int[n];` since the former requires all the elements in the vector to be set to a default value.  Moving the allocations out of the timings (timing allocation normally is not what you want to do) [you get the same results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f12b0fc164e5e556)

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see from the results, raw pointers are the clear winner in both categories. Why is this?

Because ...

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -o sp2 sp2.cpp
> ```

... you didn't enable optimization. Calling an operator overloaded for a non-fundamental type such as `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` involves a function call. Using operators of fundamental types like a raw pointer do not involve function calls.

A function call is typically slower than no function call. Over several iterations, the small overhead of the function call multiplies. However, an optimizer can expand function calls inline thereby making the disadvantage of non-fundamental types void. But only if the optimization is performed.

---

`std::deque` has an additional reason for being slower: The algorithm to access an arbitrary element of a double ended queue is more complicated than accessing an array. While `std::deque` has decent random access performance, it is not as good array has. A more appropriate use case for `std::deque` is linear iteration (using an iterator).

Furthermore, you used `std::deque::at`, which does bounds checking. The subscript operator does not do bounds checking. Bounds checking adds runtime overhead.

---

The slight edge that the raw array appears to have with the allocation speed over the `std::vector`, may be because `std::vector` zero-initializes the data.

Comment: "You'd get better performance by using an iterator." <-- How do you suggest I use an iterator for random access? That's part of what I'm timing.

Comment: @kmiklas You could use iterator for random access, but that's not what I mean. I'm saying that `std::deque` has slower random access than an array. Linear iteration is a more appropriate use case for `std::deque`. I'll clarify.

Answer (score -2):

A `std::deque` is a doubly linked list. `myDeque.at(i)` has to walk through the first i elements on every call. That is why the access to the deque is so slow.

The initialiation of `std::vector` is slow, because you don't preallocate enough memory. `std::vector` then starts with a small number of elements and usually doubles that as soon as you try to insert more. This reallocation involves calling the move constructor for all elements. Try to construct the vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> myVector{n};
```

in the vector access I wonder why you didn't use `tmp = myVector[i]`. Instead of calling the index operator, you instantiate an iterator, call its + operator and on the result you call the dereference operator. Since you are not optimizing, function calls will probably not be inlined, so that is, why std::vector access is slower than the raw pointer.

For the `std::uniqe_ptr` I suppose, that it has similar reasons as with `std::vector`. You always call the index operator on the unique pointer, which is a function call as well. Just as an experiment, can you please try and immediately after allocating the memory for `smart_p`, call `smart_p.get()` and use the raw pointer for the rest of the operations. I assume, that it will be just as fast as the raw pointer. That could prove my assumption, that it is the function calls. Then the simple advice is, enable optimizations and try again.

**kmiklas edit**:

```
Average of 2000 runs:
Method  Assign          Access
======  ======          ======
Raw:    0.0000086415    0.0000000681
Smart:  0.0000081824    0.0000000670
Deque:  0.0000204542    0.0000076554
Vector: 0.0000164252    0.0000000678
```

Comment: "can you please try and immediately after allocating the memory for smart_p, call smart_p.get()" <---- Done, edited your post with results. With this change, unique_ptr was faster!

Comment: `std::deque` is not a plain linked list. `std::deque::at` does not have to walk through the first `i` elements. That would imply that the complexity of random access was linear. But the standard requires it to have constant complexity.

Comment: Saying *A std::deque is a doubly linked list* is not quite right.  It is a list of chuncks of elements.  Otherwise it would be the same as `std::list`.

Comment: std::vector<int> myVector{n}; produces a segmentation fault. Is std::vector<int> myVector(n) acceptable?

Comment: Ah, I see. `vector<int>` is a special case. Yes, that is acceptable, of course. As your results show, the function calls make the difference. So when you switch on optimizations, the compiler can inline them all. You'll probably see no big difference between raw, and `uniqe_ptr`. I think, what you see now is mostly statistical noise. `vector will probably be slightly slower, but not much. I wouldn't expect you to be able to distinguish the difference from statistical noise.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, you are correct. I'm sorry. Anyway deque needs a more complex data structure than std::vector to fulfill its guarantees. The complexty is O(1), but the constant factor is bigger. That is I think, the reason for the much slower measured access. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @user2079303 Of course I include you in my thanks :-)